# WCF + POX + XDocument, is there a way to do it?

Tags: xml, wcf

I'm in deep trouble because I wrote a POX service w/ WCF and WebInovke and specified the input type as XElement because we need several different types of data coming into. I'm in trouble now because the service throws a 400 Bad Request if you submit an xml infoset w/ processing instructions. When I tried changing it to XDocument, the service no longer works period.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

`XElement` should work. It implements [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and so [the `DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) should have no problem serializing instances of it [as is documented here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx).

Can you post any exception information you're getting and/oryour code so we can try and help figure out what's wrong?